# How can I use a string to find the class that has the same name with the string

Tags: java, reflection

So, suppose I have a string str = "MyClass", now I want to use this str to find the MyClass so I can instantiate it, and use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple example:

```
MyClass obj = Class.forName("com.xyz.MyClass").newInstance();
```

This assumes the existence of a default constructor, and will throw various exceptions if the class cannot be found, or cannot be instantiated.

Comment: want to highlight, that class should be available for loading by the classloaders, IOW, should be present on classpath.

Comment: As skaffman pointed out there are a number of exceptions that can be thrown since you are dealing with the reflection APIs of Java. Note that newInstance() will only work in a no argument constructor is available to the class that is calling (i.e. public, package). If the constructor takes arguments, you'll have to do some more reflection lookups and calls.

Answer (score 0):

[Class.forName](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29) may do what you want, but you will need the full package path as well.

Answer (score 0):

Class myClass = [Class.forName](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String))("package.MyClass");

Object instance = myClass[.newInstance()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance());

where package is the name of the package containing MyClass